# How can I add a legend after I used lines()

Tags: r, plot, survival-analysis

first I make a CIF plot :

```
cmprsk:::plot.cuminc(forplot,ylim=c(0, 0.04),curvlab="CIF",main="Curves for Failure Hematologic P=(0:1) ")
```

then I add a 1-km curve

```
fitcs1=survfit(Surv(hem_free, hem_censor2)~1)
lines(fitcs1,fun='event',lty=2:3,lwd=0.5,mark.time=FALSE,legend="e")  #"event" plots cumulative events (f(y) = 1-y)
```

I am wondering why there is no legend for the 1-KM curve

I tried to use `legend("topleft",c("1-KM curve"),lty=2:3,lwd=0.5)` but I can't delete the label I had from my first plot.

I will be very appropriated if you can help me out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's right. You cannot delete items from a plot made with base graphics. If you are succeeding with `lines` then that's excellent evidence that `plot.cuminc` is using base graphics. Base graphics is not like ggplot2 graphics. There is no "awareness" or "object-orientation" that makes it easy to bolt in a new component when an extra line was added. You probably need to suppress the first legend with `curvlab=NA` and then build a legend from scratch with the added annotation. Post a working code example, perhaps using one of the datasets or examples in `cmprsk`.